# Django Ratelimit vs Django REST framework Throttling

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm currently using the Django [Ratelimit](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library on my `post` method while using the APIView class.

I'm looking to see if I **should** integrate the **[throttling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#throttling)** tool from Django REST framework.

After reading the DRF docs where it says: **"Throttles do not necessarily only refer to rate-limiting requests"**, I've come to the conclusion that I'm not even sure if I understand what the differences are.

Therefore, I would like to know if they are almost the same, or when one should be used over the other and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

**Throttling:**

This functionality is already in the Django rest framework, you don't have to install other packages for this.

In throttle, you can use a different type of throttling, like `AnonRateThrottle`, `UserRateThrottle`, `ScopedRateThrottle`

You can also write your own throttle class by extending the '`BaseThrottle`' class.

**Django-Ratelimit:**

It is a different package, you have to install it in order to use it.

Here, you can use @ratelimit decorator with limited parameters. like - 
    `@ratelimit(key='ip', rate='10/h')` or you can extend your class by '`RatelimitMixin`' class.

Comment: @usman-maqbool , can we use django-ratelimit package for securing the DRF !?

Comment: can we use django-ratelimit package for securing the DRF !?